# SQL trying to fusion 2 query

Tags: sql-server

i have this 2 query

```
  select  CONVERT(date, en_cours.date),COUNT(*) encours from en_cours  group by  CONVERT(date, en_cours.date) order by CONVERT(date, en_cours.date) asc

  select  CONVERT(date, clos.date),COUNT(*) clos from clos  group by  CONVERT(date, clos.date) order by CONVERT(date, clos.date) asc
```

the first one return :

```
B|1
C|1
F|20
```

and the seconde one :

```
A|4
B|8
C|7
D|1
E|9
F|10
```

i'm trying to fusion this 2 query and make it like :

```
A|4|NULL
B|8|1
C|7|1
D|1|NULL
E|9|NULL
F|10|20
```

but when i'm doing this it's given different values

```
  select  CONVERT(date, clos.date),COUNT(clos.ticket_cp),COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp)from clos left join en_cours on CONVERT(date, clos.date) = CONVERT(date, en_cours.date)   group by  CONVERT(date, clos.date) order by CONVERT(date, clos.date) asc
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing!

Comment: there is a red line under ( SqlDataReader , SqlCommand)

Comment: Compile the code and you will receive error about it.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you still help me , i have another error

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: @VigneshKumarA [take a lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116661/can-not-open-the-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each of your queries inside a CTE and join them:

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select CONVERT(date, en_cours.date) date1, COUNT(*) encours 
    from en_cours  
    group by CONVERT(date, en_cours.date) 
  )  
  cte2 as (
    select CONVERT(date, clos.date) date2, COUNT(*) clos 
    from clos  
    group by CONVERT(date, clos.date) 
  )
select c1.date1, c1.encours, c2.clos
from cte1 c1 left join cte2 c2 
on c2.date2 = c1.date1
order by c1.date1 asc
```

Change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN` if there is a case that the 2nd query may contain dates that do not exist in the 1st query.

Answer (score 0):

the scenario for using the direct database call is a little fragile, because if you have any database change you will have to wait for the publication time in stores to change queries.
But for your scenario try to include System.Data for integration with sql commands.